# move image to the top without altering the responsive view

Tags: html, css

hello i want to move the image to the top without altering the responsive view when the browser resizes , i don't know  if i have some problem with the margin of the carousel or the column or both, i move the image with this code

```
#img1{ 

    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-size: auto 0;


}
```

but the responsive view is altering, this is my css code and html code.

```
@media (orientation: landscape) { 
    .carousel-item.active,
    .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-item-prev {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:96vh;
    }
}


.carousel .carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30em;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.carousel-item.active img {
  width:300%;
}


.carousel-control-next-icon{
    background-image:url('imagenes2/arrow next.png');
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon{
    background-image:url('imagenes2/previous arrow.png');
}


 .d-block.img-fluid  {
    max-height: 100%;

}



.fila2 .carousel-inner  img { 
  max-width: 100%; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,171,235);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(178,205,73,1.00);


}

.carousel-control-prev{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 75.5%;
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
}

.carousel-control-next{
        max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 75.5%;

    border-right: 2px solid rgba(178,205,73,1.00);
}
```

this is my html code of the carousel

```
<div class="row fila2">
<!----inicio columna 2----->                <div class="col-12 imagenesc">

<!----inicio carousel----->      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagenes/20130819180556.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagenes/20130819180644.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>

<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Nextborder</span> </a><!----fin carousel----->      </div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div id="img1">
<img  src="imagenes2/prueba.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
</div>
</div>



</div>
```

this is a [image: screenshot] of my site, i want to move to the top the image without altering the reponsive view

[image: thi is the responsive view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide complete source code of the html file, so readers can look at your problem with the right libraries and files?

There seems to be another source of positioning info that prevents the image in question from getting to the top.